# Can I use my oem windows CD for a different laptop?

Tags: windows

I was wondering if an OEM windows 7 home edition CD can be used for other computers that already have a registered version of Windows 7 home on them. My friend has a laptop with Windows 7 on it and I have multiple computers with Windows 7 home on them. Is the CD key integrated to each cd or will windows figure out that the computer was already registered and verify the installation?

Comment: Its not the cd that matters, its the Product Key, that being said, OEM software is tied to the hardware it was originally installed on for life, once the product key is activated it is tied to that hardware.

Comment: Do you think a desktop CD would be interchangeable for a laptop, for example a Sony or dell?

Comment: That won't matter at all. You just might have an issue if say the Sony disc has their drivers on it.

Comment: It depends on the manufacturer.  I have successfully used the official MS ISO on HP systems with there product key.  I had to call MS and manually activate the code with the 10 set 5 of digits, but it works.   You can also try http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-recovery    Another company may not work.  I have done this with at least 3 hp desktop and 2 laptops.

Comment: OEM windows activates automatically tho using the internet. How does Microsoft know the user purchased the disk for a new computer and the product code is used if it's not asking for it?